# Derivation of the exoplanetary flux observed at Earth (solid angle problem)

Tags: astronomy, radiation, atmospheric-science, geometry, intensity

I'm having issues understanding how Sara Seager, in her book "Exoplanet Atmospheres", determines the solid angle subjected to a detector on Earth. By the figure:

[image]

The solid angle was defined as:

$\Omega = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{R_p/D_\oplus} \sin \omega d\omega d \phi$

where,

$\omega = \frac{R_p}{D_\oplus} \sin \vartheta $

I can't see $\omega$ described this way by the figure. If anyone can shed some light on how this was done, I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: What are $\Omega$ and all the other quantities in your question?

Comment: @ProfRob $\Omega$ - solid angle, $R_p$ - planet radius and $D_\oplus$ - distance from the planet's surface to the detector on earth. The problem uses the colatitude spherical polar coordiante system,

Comment: Well according to that definition, $\Omega = \pi R_p^2/D^2$.

Comment: Is the confusion related to the small angle approximation used for the final equation? The expression uses the fact that $\sin \omega \approx \omega$ and $R_p \ll D$ to a very good approximation. Also $\omega$ in the integration appears not to be exactly what's shown in the diagram. It's implied that a line should be drawn from the detector to a point on the planet $x$ from the line between the center and detector, defining $\omega$ as the angle subtended at the detector. This differs from the diagrams where that line is to a tangent point on the planet.

Comment: @FTT Yes, the confusion is in the last expression. How does $\sin\vartheta$ appear?

Comment: @Fitzroy I think the exact expression would be $R_p \sin \nu = x = \left ( D - R_p \cos \nu \right ) \sin \omega$. From the suggested approximations, this gives $R_p \sin \nu \approx D \omega$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\omega$ appears to be the angle subtended from the Earth to the point on the star that is a height $x$ above the z-axis in the bottom diagram.
$$\omega \approx \sin \omega = \frac{x}{D_\oplus}= \frac{R_p \sin \vartheta}{D_\oplus}$$

The total solid angle should then be
a double integral of $\sin \omega d\omega d\phi$ where the limits on $\omega$ are zero (a line towards the closest point to the star) and $R_p/D_\oplus$ (a line towards the "pole" of the star), assuming that $D_\oplus \gg R_p$.

The integral evaluates to
$$\Omega = 2\pi\left(1 - \cos \frac{R_p}{D_\oplus}\right)\ ,$$
but given the approximations already used, we can say $\cos \alpha \approx 1 - \alpha^2/2$ and obtain $\Omega = \pi R_p^2/D_\oplus^2$.

I must say I don't really understand why this approach is being taken. It might make sense if you can't assume $D_\oplus \gg R_p$, but then the upper limit of the integral would not be $R_p/D_\oplus$.